# Is the co-projection of the projection of a Borel set Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Reading the classical book  of Kechris "Classical descriptive set theory", I found the following facts

The projection of a Lebesgue measurable set need not be Lebesgue measurable, but the projection of a Borel set is an analytic set (Souslin set, $\bf \Sigma_{1}^{1}$) which is Lebesgue measurable.

If a set  is analytic its complement is co-analytic ($\bf \Pi_{1}^{1}$) and hence also Lebesgue measurable.

The co-projection   of a co-analytic set is co-analytic and hence Lebesgue measurable.

It easily follows that the composition of two projections or the composition of two coprojections of a Borel set must be Lebesgue measurable.

The question is what happens if we compose these two operations i.e., take the co-projection of a projection of a Borel set. Is the result Lebesgue measurable?

I can prove that the  resulting set is a difference of a Lebesgue measurable and a PCA set ($\bf \Sigma^{1}_{2}$) but it is known that within ZFC  it can not be decided whether  the latter are or are not Lebesgue measurable.

I still believe that I miss something obvious and such sets are measurable.

To simplify notation assume that we are talkig of subsets of the finite dimensional Euclidean space.

The projection is $$\pi: X\times Y \supset A\ni (x,y)\to x\in \pi(A)\subseteq X$$

The co-projection $\pi'$ related to a projection  $$\tilde \pi: X=U\times V\ni (u,v)\to  u\in U,$$ is defined as $$\pi'(B)=(\tilde \pi (B^{c}))^{c},$$ where $c$ stnads for the complement in the respective space.

Comment: How is "co-projection of the projection of a Borel set" different from "complement of the projection of a coanalytic set" (which is just ${\bf\Pi^1_2}$)?

Comment: And a set is Lebesgue measurable iff its complement is.  So if there is a $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2}^1$ set $A$ which is not Lebesgue measurable, then its complement is the "co-projection of a projection" of a Borel set and is not Lebesgue measurable either.  So this is equivalent to the undecidable question of whether $\mathbf{\Sigma}_2^1$ sets are Lebesgue measurable.  Right?

Comment: You seem to be right. I hoped that the image of the projection   will somehow ''land'' outside the ''bad locus'' in the domain of the co-projection. This was justified by the observation  that the co-projection of the projection of the generators of the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets are Lebesgue mesurable (say the co-projection of the projection of open sets is measurable).